# mongodb : check if the field exists in the JSON

Tags: json, mongodb

In mongo shell I'm trying to check a JSON pushed into a variable has the field name or not.However, I'm getting error for missing something.

```
var p= db.monit.findOne({_id: 0})
if ("p.pay[0].reR": {$exists: true})
    print(p.pay[0].reR)
```

In the above code, I'm trying to check if `reR` field exists in the JSON document pushed in variable `p`.

Comment: @felix: It is working.......... Can you post this as answer. I will mark after you post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two different things.
 [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/exists/) has to be used inside a mongoDB query.
 What you need here is the javascript method [obj.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/hasOwnProperty). 
Use it like this:

```
 var p= db.monit.findOne({_id: 0})
 if ( p.pay[0].hasOwnProperty("reR")){
        print(p.pay[0].reR);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using,

```
var p=db.monit.findOne({_id: 0});
var q = db.monit.findOne("p.pay[0].reR": {$exists: true});
if(q)
 print(p.pay[0].reR);
```

Comment: It gives me null value. Though i modify to get solution from this query, I am looking for an optimized query where i do not look back into collection after i load data into variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** operator within the query as:

```
var p = db.monit.findOne({
    "_id": 0,
    "pay.0.reR": { "$exists": true }
})
if (p !== null) printjson(p.pay[0].reR)
```

This will look for a document that statisfies the above query where the _id has value 0 `AND` there **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** an embedded document with a property `reR` as the first element of the `pay` array (using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)).

Comment: I cannot check this at the initial level because either the field exists or not I need to perform some other operations and if the field exists there are extra calculations to be carried out. So, I wanted to check if the field exists in the variable `p` or not